# affected_rows not working with a non-default database in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to use affected_rows on a database which is not the default one. The query works properly but I'm getting an error when checking affected_rows.

This is the code:

```
function activate_tlf($tlf) {
    $tlfDB = $this->load->database('tlfDB', TRUE);
    $tlfDB->where('tlf', $tlf);
    $q_get = $tlfDB->get('control');
    if ($q_get->num_rows()>0) {
        $q_delete = $tlfDB->delete('control', array('tlf' => $tlf));
        if ($tlfDB->affected_rows > 0) $result = TRUE;
        else $result = FALSE;
    } else $result = FALSE;
    $tlfDB->close();
    $this->load->database();
    return $result;
}
```

And it's giving me this:
*Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$affected_rows*

As I understand it, *$this->db* is used when you want to work with the default database, so I'm using the new db object for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `$tlfDB->affected_rows` should be

```
$tlfDB->affected_rows();
```

Because it's a method, not property. [Check here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html).

Comment: This is correct. Also, you can improve readability a bit by removing the "if then", and simply write $result = $tlfDB->affected_rows() > 0;